# webcam flipped aka v4l1compat.so troubles

Tags: 14.04, skype, webcam

So since I installed 14.04 an old issue re-arises:
In cheese my webcam works fine, in skype its upside down. 
Before you could fix that by:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

but now you can't, as I understand, because you end up here:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
```

which results in:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
```

Now it was suggested to use the 32bit version in

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
```

but there is only the one version in x86_64, I searched my whole system, nothing...
How is this fixable? Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: I worked it out! Combining the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/315643/ld-preload-fails-with-skype?lq=1 and the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/463337/asus-k50ij-webcam-problem it worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix for this problem:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

Did the trick for my Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. If you haven't got the 32bit library install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
```

I hope that works for you too.

Regards
pecuna

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I installed libv4l-dev but there is still no folder libv4l in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ how did you make it appear?

Comment: I don't know. I just install libv4l-dev and nothing else. I should have done something before that to have it :(

Answer (score 3):

You have to install 32 bit (i386) version of libv4l-0:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libv4l-0:i386
```

then start Skype with this command:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
```

or modify the `Exec` command in `/usr/share/applications/skype.desktop`

Comment: This is the same as http://askubuntu.com/a/463443/158442.

Comment: @muru The other answer says "libv4l-dev" whereas this one says "libv4l-0:i386". Could this be the missing piece to solve the 32-bit problem?

Comment: @MadMike ah, yes. You're right: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&section=all&arch=i386&keywords=libv4l%2Fv4l1compat.so&searchon=contents The poster of the accepted answer probably already had it installed.

Answer (score 0):

A little nice extension to the solution:

```
sudo vi /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
```

and add the above mentioned add (`LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so`)
to the line

```
Exec=env  PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype %U
```

so that this line is

```
Exec=env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype %U
```

Afterwards the skype icon in the dock does also work.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with vertically flipped camera.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
```

didn't help. But after I installed Qt V4l2 test utility (*qv4l2*), and switching "Vertical flip" option in User controls tab off and back on (it was on by default), afterwards starting Skype, the camera behaved normally.
So I used command line control utility *v4l2-ctl* to set the *vertical_flip* option right before skype starts.
Created a new launcher script for skype:

```
#!/bin/bash
v4l2-ctl -c vertical_flip=0
v4l2-ctl -c vertical_flip=1
sleep 5
skype %U
```

and changed the desktop launcher for skype to execute this script (or if you want to run skype when your session starts, you can create an entry for it in Settings / Session and Startup.
P.S.: Not sure why 5 sec sleep is required, but it didn't work for me without it :-).