# Asus K50IJ Webcam problem

Tags: webcam, camera

Hello again Ubuntu community!
I have a problem again. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 32bit on my Asus k50IJ laptop and whenever i try to make a skype call with the camera on it flips my image upside down. I've searched a lot of threads and no luck. Maybe someone could give an opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install libv4l-0

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-0
```

then change skype.desktop by editing

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
```

and replace the line starting with `Exec=` like that:

```
Exec=sh -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype %U'
```

Hope it works.